# RadioButtonFor in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, radiobuttonfor

Can someone provide a simple example of how to properly use Html.RadioButtonFor?  Let's say it's a simple scenario where my model has a string property named Gender.  I want to display two radio buttons: "Male" and "Female".

What is the most clean way to implement this while retaining the selected value in an Edit view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc/2590001#2590001) deals with RadioButtonListFor and the answer addresses your question too (@Larsenal it also includes labels with the "for" attribute)

Answer (score 26):

```
Male: <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Male") %>
Female: <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Female") %>
```

Comment: That's pretty basic, but I'd argue that a proper use would include <label> tags with a "for" attribute matching it to a radio button.

Comment: Expanding on @Larsenal's comment, you can do so like this:`<%= Html.Label("Gender1", "Male:")%><%= Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "Male", new {@id="Gender1"}) %>`

Comment: Upvoted @JustinP8 and downvoated the answer - two radiobuttonfor's without the @id= give the same id for two html elements which is really nasty!

Comment: To add to JustinP8's comment, note that setting the id like this won't work properly with nested models.