# asp.net mvc radioButtonFor in forEach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, radiobuttonfor

Does anyone know why this isn't working?  any source code changes would be great.

```
<% foreach (var i in Model.talentImages) { %>
                        <div style="padding:15px;">
                            <img src="<%: i.uri %>" width="95" height="84" alt="" style="float:left; padding:0px 20px 0px 0px" />
                            <div style="padding:30px 10px 10px 10px">
                               <%: Html.RadioButtonFor("group-" + i.uriId.ToString(), i.isApproved)%> Approved <br />
                               <%: Html.RadioButtonFor("group-" + i.uriId.ToString(), i.isApproved)%> Deny <br />
                            </div>
                            <hr width="0"/>
                            <%= Html.RadioButton("isProfileePicGroup", i.isProfilePic, false)%> Make Profile Picture <br />
                        </div>  
                        <hr />
                    <%} %>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you give a little bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Double **i** in line

```
<img src="<%: ii.uri %>"
```

Also, **Html.RadioButtonFor** takes a lambda as the first parameter. See [RadioButtonFor in ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588699/radiobuttonfor-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

Answer (score 0):

As Jakub rightly pointed out, RadioButtonFor takes a lambda expression, along with that I wanted to point out one more thing, all ur radio buttons should have same name. Else they wont be mutually exclusive.