# Set @Html.RadioButtonFor as Checked by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radiobuttonfor

I am not able to set the default radio button to "Checked" !
I am using @Html.RadioButtonFor :

```
<div id="private-user">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "type1", new { @class="type-radio" , **@Checked="checked"** }) 1
</div>
<div id="proff-user">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "type2", new { @class="type-radio" }) 2
</div>
```

Is it possible to set a radio button as cheched using  @Html.RadioButtonFor  ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here [RadioButtonFor in ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588699/radiobuttonfor-in-asp-net-mvc-2) or for list [Has anyone implement RadioButtonListFor<T> for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc/2590001#2590001)

If you are using an Enum see this answer [pass enum to html.radiobuttonfor MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621013/pass-enum-to-html-radiobuttonfor-mvc3)

Comment: Even if, in my case, UserType is an "enum". Should I transforme it to some other kind of object encapsulating the enum UserType ?

Answer (score 5):

In your controller action set the value of the `UserType` property on your view model to the corresponding value:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...

    // preselect the second radio button
    model.UserType = "type2";
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view:

```
<div id="private-user">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "type1", new { @class="type-radio" }) 1
</div>
<div id="proff-user">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UserType, "type2", new { @class="type-radio" }) 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this posting, they have answered your question (albeit MVC 2, but its the same thing in this context):

[How to Set RadioButtonFor() in ASp.net MVC 2 as Checked by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598668/how-to-set-radiobuttonfor-in-asp-net-mvc-2-as-checked-by-default)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your View Model, just initialize the property to the value that you want.

```
public YourViewModel(){
    UserType = "type1";
}
```

That way your postbacks will use whatever value you want and you don't have to set the value in the controller.