# How to get the HTML id generated by asp.net MVC EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I use the HTML Helpers to render my fields:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.Surname)%>
```

and the output would be something like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="User_Surname" 
          name="User.Surname" type="text" value="" />
```

The helper uses the className + '.' è fieldName to build the id.
I need to pass the id to a jQuery function. Is there a way to have it without hardcoding it?
Maybe an helper which can use the ASP.NET MVC2 conventions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've followed the instructions of Mac's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc) and I've built my own custom extension:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string HtmlIdNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return (GetHtmlIdNameFor(expression));
    }

    private static string GetHtmlIdNameFor<TModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
        {
            var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
            string name = GetHtmlIdNameFor(methodCallExpression);
            return name.Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1).Replace('.', '_');

        }
        return expression.Body.ToString().Substring(expression.Parameters[0].Name.Length + 1).Replace('.', '_');
    }

    private static string GetHtmlIdNameFor(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        var methodCallExpression = expression.Object as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCallExpression != null)
        {
            return GetHtmlIdNameFor(methodCallExpression);
        }
        return expression.Object.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've imported my application's namespace

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcApplication2" %>
```

and finally I can use my code like this:

```
<%=Html.HtmlIdNameFor(m=>m.Customer.Name)%>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you need a 'using System.Linq.Expressions;' for this to work. Sweet code anyway :)

Comment: I think you also need to replace '[' & ']' (if you are referencing array elements)

Answer (score 143):

ASP.NET MVC 4 has [Html.IdFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) built in that can return this:

```
@Html.IdFor(m => m.User.Surname)
```

Answer (score 44):

See this question: [get the generated clientid for a form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418898/get-the-generated-clientid-for-a-form-field), this is my answer:

I use this helper:

```
public static partial class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ClientIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(
              htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(
                  ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
    }
}
```

Use it just as you would any other helper: `@Html.ClientIdFor(model=>model.client.email)`

Comment: Per my answer, this is now built into ASP.NET 4 with Html.IdFor()

Comment: thanks so much i needed that. html.IdFor() didnt help me becouse im making a custom helper ,

Answer (score 7):

unless you create your own User.Surname EditorTemplate which you pass in some HTML attributes you won't be able to do this with `EditorFor`

However you can use `TextBoxFor` and set the id

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.Surname, new { id = "myNewId" })%>
```

---

On the topic of retrieving this element with a jQuery selector you can achieve this without having to hardcode by using some of the [ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/). Using that you could probably still use `EditorFor` and just select it with `$("[id^='Surname`]")`. If you're trying to select this specific element there's really no way to NOT hardcode SOMETHING in your jQuery code.

Comment: Adding the HTML attributes is the EASIEST way.  Much easier than writing your own extension methods