# How to read arrays generated by EditorFor using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am quite confused with technique that I am using. I am using EditorFor to display values.

The code for the values to be generated are as follows:

```
    <tr>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Authorized)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.UserName) </td>
           </tr>
```

My aim here is upon the Checkbox is being checked, I need to post the ID value as follows:

```
 $("input:checkbox").live('click', function () {
            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {

                var ID = $(this).parent().parent().find('#ID').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%=Url.Action("Edit","Employee") %>',
                    data: JSON.stringify(ID),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function () {
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert("Error: " & request.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }            });
```

However, var ID = $(this).parent().parent().find('#ID').val(); is undefined.  How can I he read the ID value from the following generated HTML:

```
  <td><input id="Employee_0__ID" name="Employee[0].ID" type="hidden" value="1100" /><input id="Employee_0__Authorized" name="Employee[0].Authorized" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Employee[0].Authorized" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
<td>user </td>
```

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829193/how-to-get-the-html-id-generated-by-asp-net-mvc-editorfor

Comment: you have 2 hiddden fields in that checkbox's td, which one are you after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what value you looking for?

Would this.

```
var ID = $(this).parent().parent().find('#ID').attr('value');
```

or this

```
var ID = $(this).parent().parent().find('#ID').attr('id');
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML specified this should suffice as the hidden element is the previous sibling of the checkbox in the DOM

```
var ID = $(this).prev().val();
```