# Is it possible to give my HtmlHelper textbox an id ?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to give my HtmlHelper textbox an id ? 
For instance like

```
<input type="submit" id="someid" />
```

In this case it would be for 
Html.Textbox

The reason I am asking this is because I want to use this info 
in a javascript function and get the value like this

```
(document.getElementById('someid').value)
```

Suggestions anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify some metadata when creating the link on the server.

```
[C#]

    <%= Html.ActionLink(“Edit Record”, “Edit”, new {Id=3})

[VB]

    <%= Html.ActionLink(“Edit Record”, “Edit”, New With {.Id=3})%>
```

Taken from: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If using the `Html.TextboxFor()` method, `@Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.Property);`, your textbox will have an id with the name of the property.  My example above would create an HTML tag of

`<input type="text" id="Property" name="Property"/>`

Answer (score 1):

As Tommy said, The element will be created with the same name as of the Property Id. But you can override it by using this Overload

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@id="myNewId" })
```

This will create an input element with an Id "`myNewId`" . But the name stays same as the property Name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the textbox an id, you can ask ASP.NET MVC to tell you what it is, as per the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829193/how-to-get-the-html-id-generated-by-asp-net-mvc-editorfor).