# ASP.NET MVC Exclude Data Annotation Attribute in Html.ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use the EF-CF, and have the following entities:

**Countries, Companies**

Companies has a property called CountryId with StringLength attribute and the min and max restrictions (**min 3 chars, max 3 chars**, country id is *ISO-Alpha-3*). When the user needs to create a Company, I show a  html element with all available countries. This is perfect!

However, when the I execute the jquery validator to the form, this checks for 3 selected options and not the length selected option value.

I need the StringLengthAttribute in my Country Model, I cannot remove it.

I hope to "remove" or "hide" the StringLengthAttribute in the call:
**@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question. A possible solution would be to use a ViewModel to pass to the view as oppose to using the `Company` entity directly. This would allow you to add or remove data annotations without changing the entity model. Then map the data from the new `CompanyViewModel` over to the `Company` entity model to be saved to the database.

For example, the `Company` entity might look something like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeAmount { get; set; }
    [StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string CountryId {get; set; }
}
```

Now in the MVC project a ViewModel can be constructed similar to the `Company` entity:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage="Company name needs to be 25 characters or less!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeAmount { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

Using a ViewModel means more view presentation orientated annotations can be added without overloading entities with unnecessary mark-up.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Chris! Good Idea. I found the next solution. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16617966/2390800)

Answer (score 0):

Ready!

I remove the rule for the  html control.

$("#@(Html.HtmlIdNameFor(model => model.CountryId))").rules("remove", "rangelength");

The "rangelength" is the jquery validation rule for the StringLengthAttribute.

Where "Html.HtmlIdNameFor" is a helper to get the "Id" generated by ASP.NET MVC.
Review [How to get the HTML id generated by asp.net MVC EditorFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829193/how-to-get-the-html-id-generated-by-asp-net-mvc-editorfor)