# RadioButtonFor in asp.net mvc only creates one radiobutton

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I 'm trying to create RadioButtonFor or CheckBoxFor for my Question.   I created this model:

> ```
>     public class Question
>     {
>         public int ID { get; set; }
>         public string Question1 { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Answer
>     {
>         public int ID { get; set; }
>         public string Answer1 { get; set; }
>         public int QId  { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class AnModelView
>     {
>         public Answer Answers { get; set; }
>         public IQueryable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

In my view I am trying this:

`<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Answers.QId, new SelectList(Model.Questions.Select(qu => new RadioButtonList {    DataValueField = qu.ID.ToString(),  DataTextField = qu.Question1 }), "Value", "Text"))%>`

but the output is only one radiobutton.  How can I get multiple radiobuttons - one for each answer

Comment: u can use the radioibuttonlist helper from here: http://awesome.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a list of radiobuttons, not a single one.  Check out this question re: Html.RadioButtonListFor... [Has anyone implement RadioButtonListFor<T> for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I'm surprised for this why all this, are there another solution for my problem

Comment: levy ok I need this but how to bind model => model.Answers.QId with select value