# RadioButtonFor not selecting value in editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I want the default gender to be female, so I set that up in the action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Person { Gender = "F" }; // default is female
    return View(model);
}
```

Finally, the view renders everything like this:

```
@model Person

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
}
```

This all works as expected. Now, let's say that instead of a simple textbox, I want to display the gender as a more intuitive pair of radio buttons. So I make the following template and save it to Shared/EditorTemplates/Gender.cshtml:

```
@model string
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model, "F") Female
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model, "M") Male
```

Finally I decorate Gender with `[UIHint("Gender")]`.

Gender is now properly rendered with radio buttons, which is great, BUT...

**The problem**

Female no longer comes pre selected as the default value and instead I end up with the two radio buttons blank. Am I missing something?

Interestingly, if I move `RadioButtonFor` from the template to the view (changing `model => model` to `model => model.Gender`), then everything works as expected. I know this is a viable workaround, but these templated helpers are such an amazing, addictive convenience that I would rather exhaust all possibilities before letting them go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it's ugly but the following might work:

```
@model string
@Html.RadioButton("", "F", Model == "F") Female
@Html.RadioButton("", "M", Model == "M") Male
```

The problem with the RadioButton helper is that if the first argument is null or empty it will always consider it as non checked thus making this helper inappropriate for editor templates.

Here's an excerpt from the MVC source code which illustrates what I mean:

```
bool isChecked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && string.Equals(htmlHelper.EvalString(name), b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

As an alternative you could use a [custom HTML helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc/2590001#2590001) to generate a list of radio buttons.

Comment: +1 and answer. Worked a treat! It's not that ugly either. If anything, I'd rather live with the "ugliness" if I get to keep my `@Html.EditorForModels()`'s Thanks! :)

Comment: I took this idea and expanded on it. I pass a List<Dictionary<string,string>> to my editor template as added ViewData that I use to create the radio buttons. My template looks like this

Comment: Would you mind if I edit your answer to include a more complete description of why `isChecked` returns false (being that `name` is the result of `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)` which returns and empty `string`) so I can dupe hammer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451373/radiobuttonfor-in-editortemplate-does-not-select-the-radiobutton#47451373)?

Answer (score 0):

I took this idea and expanded on it. I pass a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` to my editor template as added `ViewData` that I use to create the radio buttons. My template looks like this

```
@model string
@{
    var buttons = (List<Dictionary<string, string>>)ViewData["Buttons"];
}
@foreach (var button in buttons) {
    <label class="radio inline">
        @Html.RadioButton(Html.NameForModel().ToHtmlString(), Model, Model == button["Value"], new { id = Html.IdForModel() }) @button["Label"]
    </label>
}
```

this is what I'm passing to my `EditorFor` as additional `ViewData`

```
new { Buttons = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> { new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Label", "Commercial" }, { "Value", "Y" } }, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Label", "Residential" }, { "Value", "N" } } } }
```

Granted I could add this to a ViewModel type and pass that to the View from my controller, however it was quicker to do it in the `cshtml` file.