# Is there an easy way to create a list of buttons and set the selected value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently i am creating two buttons and setting the selected value this way:

```
@if (Model.Test_Emne == null)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, 1) <span>Ja</span>
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, 0) <span>Nej</span>

}

@if (Model.Test_Emne == true)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, 1, new { @checked = "checked" }) <span>Ja</span>
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, 0) <span>Nej</span>
} else if (Model.Test_Emne == false)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, 1) <span>Ja</span>
    <br />
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, 0, new { @checked = "checked" }) <span>Nej</span>
}
```

I have a lot of radio buttons on my page, so i am looking for a way to do this with less code.

I have also seen:

[Has anyone implement RadioButtonListFor<T> for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc/2590001#2590001)

 and 
http://jonlanceley.blogspot.com/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html

Are these the only options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems shorter way to achieve the same:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, true) <span>Ja</span>
<br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Test_Emne, false) <span>Nej</span>
```

Possible scenarios when rendering the view:

- `Test_Emne = null` => none of the radios is checked
- `Test_Emne = true` => the first radio is checked
- `Test_Emne = false` => the second radio is checked

Possible scenarios when posting back:

- If none of the radios is checked the `Test_Emne` property will be set to `null`
- If the first radio is checked the `Test_Emne` property will be set to `true`
- If the second radio is checked the `Test_Emne` property will be set to `false`

---

UPDATE:

This could be extended to any property and any numbers of radio buttons. For example:

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

and then:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Foo, "value1") <span>Foo 1</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Foo, "value2") <span>Foo 2</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Foo, "value3") <span>Foo 3</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Foo, "value4") <span>Foo 4</span>
...
```

and then depending of the value of the Foo property the corresponding radio button will be selected. For example if you set `model.Foo = "value3";` the third radio will be preselected.

Comment: This works very nice with booleans. Thanks! Is there a similar approach, when i have five radio buttons that have a value from 1-5, and the selected button should be the one which has the same value as a property (ie. property name: Bes_Af_Value) ?

Comment: @Kenci, of course. This works with any type you want. I have updated my answer with an example.