# asp.net mvc 3 razor change model value in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have model with bool property IsMale. In view i have table with values how i can change value?

I tried this:

```
 <td>
            @if (item.IsMale == true)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "Male")
            }
            else
            {
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "Female")
            }
        </td>
```

But im getting error:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

And in create view how i can make radio buttons >Male >Female and return it in bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsMale)
```

I see that it is a radio button you want...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, true)

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsMale, false)
```

Comment: A check box would be a very unusual way to present such a choice to the user: "[ ] I am a male person (please do not check this box if you are a female person)"

Answer (score 2):

```
<td>

  @Html.Display(item.IsMale ? "Male" : "Female" )

</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.DisplayFor` takes a property of the model and outputs the value of that property. What you are trying to do is printing a hardcoded string. You don't need `DisplayFor` for that. Just try:

```
<td>
    @if (item.IsMale)
    {
        <text>Male</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>Female</text>
    }
</td>
```

A better design would be if you don't make the gender a boolean value. You may want to add "Unspecified" or whatever later. If you make the gender a "first class" entity, the names "male" vs. "female" as well as the radio buttons don't have to be hardcoded:

Say you have a class called "Gender" with a property "Name". Your modelItem would then have a property "Gender" with is an object of type "Gender".

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Gender.Name)</td>
```

and for the radios you could retrieve the whole list of available genders from your data source and put them as a RadioButtonList into the ViewModel. Then you can simply use:

```
@Html.RadioButtonListFor(modelItem => modelItem.AllGenders)
```

See also [Has anyone implement RadioButtonListFor<T> for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc/2590001#2590001)