# Use Radio Buttons instead of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am able to dynamically populate `@Html.DropDownList()` from a dataset. The code below works fine for this.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myList
    {
        get
        {
            ReportAPI.ReportsAPI ws = new ReportAPI.ReportsAPI();
            DataSet ds = ws.GetReportDataSet(userguid, reportguid);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = dr["text"].ToString(),
                    Value = dr["value"].ToString(),
                });
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

public ActionResult NewSubscriber()
    {

        ViewData["subscriptionplanx"] = myList;

        return View();
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@Html.DropDownList("subscriptionplanx")
```

Now, instead of using a DropDownList, I want to use radio buttons instead. How would I do this?

Comment: There has been some work on HtmlHelpers for RadioButtonLists - here: http://jonlanceley.blogspot.com/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Furthermore, you should also use a "ViewModel" instead of throwing stuff into ViewData. ViewData is really awkward given its dynamic nature, and you'll have to use HiddenFields to get data back into POST actions anyway. Just create a ViewModel for the View in question, and you can eliminate all the casting hassle with ViewData.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `HtmlHelper` is probably the most elegant solution.
Anyway, if you're looking for something straighforward, try this:

```
@foreach(SelectListItem item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["subscriptionplanx"])
{
    <input type="radio" name="subscriptionplanx" value="@item.Value" />@item.Text <br />
}
```

Comment: Ok. Your code works in Create view, But in Edit view, Radio buttons are not selected.

Comment: @oneNiceFriend You mean if it should be selected based on values from the DB? `item` should have the selected state, so just use it to set the `checked=true` property of the `input` element.