# How do I select a type by using a radiobutton list in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, types, radio-button

I'm new to MVC. I can't figure out how to bind a property that can have different types to radiobuttons, like for example:

```
public class Job { public string Name { get; set; } }

public class Carpenter : Job { }

public class Unemployed : Job { }

public class Painter : Job { }

public class Person
{
    public Person() { this.Job = new Unemployed(); }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

That is; a person has job of some sort. Now I like to have a view where the user can select a job for a person. I'd like to use radiobuttons to display all avalable job types. I'd also like the persons current job type to be selected as default, and of course I would like the person to have her job type updated on postback. I'm trying to use Razor. How would you do this?

Comment: Is there really any reason for each job type to be determined by the class of which it is an instance? Why not just a string? The way this is implemented looks very odd.

Comment: It's just an example. There could be alot of properties and methods on the Job types. Why do you think it looks odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a `string` model property with an identifier for the job type:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string JobType { get; set; }
}
```

You can then create a bunch of radiobuttons in your view where the values are all available job types. Then, utilize a factory class:

```
public static class JobFactory
{
    public Job GetJob(string id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case "CA":
                return new Carpenter();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call this in your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(EmployeeViewModel m)
{
    var person = new Person();
    person.Job = JobFactory.GetJob(m.JobType);
    ...
}
```

You might also benefit from switching out the string ID for an enum and using `RadioButtonListFor` in your view. There's an answer here that demonstrates this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590001/1043198

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks... but is there a way to use the Person as the model directly, whithout having to create two new "managing" classes (and an enum)?

Comment: You could probably use reflection to convert the `Job` type to and from a string in the view and create a custom model binder that will resolve types, but this will likely be messy. Not to mention that you should be using view models anyway as it is both (a) more secure than using business entities as models (helping to prevent things like model injection); and (b) creates a clearer separation of concerns between the view and the model.

Comment: If you're only using this here, you could bundle the factory method as a static method on the view model, so you don't have additional classes floating around.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer! I must say that the more I learn about ASP.MVC, the more I dislike it. This was really easy in Web forms. I feel I'm turning into a grumpy old man.

Comment: Each to his own, I suppose. I, personally, find ASP.NET MVC to be a much cleaner approach than all of the black-box events and web controls in Web Forms, not to mention the faked "persistence" of view state. It comes at the cost of a slightly greater setup, but once you get into the habit of creating a model class for each view you will start to find that things are much tidier and scale much smoother than they did with Web Forms.